# Sampling on result of dataframe.groupby()

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I've a Pandas dataframe, which looks like this:

```
      Col1      Col2      Col3
        1         A         1
        1         B         4
        1         C         5
        1         D         2
        2         A         3
        2         B         3
        2         C         5
        2         D         1
        3         A         4
        3         B         5
        3         C         2
        3         D         3
```

I'm facing problem with the task of:

- grouping the dataframe in two dataframes grouped by the "Col1" values in the ratio of 1:1.

So the result will look as follows:

Dataframe1

```
      Col1      Col2      Col3
        1         B         4
        1         D         2
        2         A         3
        2         B         3
        3         A         4
        3         B         5
```

Dataframe2

```
      Col1      Col2      Col3
        1         A         1
        1         C         5
        2         C         5
        2         D         1
        3         C         2
        3         D         3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```
In [230]: dfs = {n: g for n, g in df.groupby(df.groupby('Col1').cumcount() % 2)}  # or // 2

In [231]: dfs[0]
Out[231]:
    Col1 Col2  Col3
0      1    A     1
2      1    C     5
4      2    A     3
6      2    C     5
8      3    A     4
10     3    C     2

In [232]: dfs[1]
Out[232]:
    Col1 Col2  Col3
1      1    B     4
3      1    D     2
5      2    B     3
7      2    D     1
9      3    B     5
11     3    D     3
```

Comment: Ratios like 2:3:5 can be done using %10 and then doing some set operations.